# Complexity of finding number of unique paths between two vertices in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Suppose I start from some vertex (m,n) and wants to reach a vertex (i, j), and there are valid paths on the graph (value 1) and invalid ones (value 0). I want to find the unique number of paths to (i, j).

My current idea has the following pseudo code:

1. Mark a current node from the starting point as visiting using a placeholder variable, store original state.
2. DFS into a neighbouring node, where DFS handles out of bounds and invalid paths. If DFS enters a node visiting (not visited) at the moment, stop the DFS as there's a cycle.
3. If the DFS finds (i,j) increment the value to return.
4. After DFS, restore the cell's original state.

Testing on several test cases, it works, but I'm not convinced that this is the best solution since the complexities are potentially very large. I'm not very sure if this is the right complexity:

1. Time: O(M+N) time for each DFS, and performs DFS O(MN) time potentially, so O(MN * (M+N)) time.
2. 4 calls per cell of DFS, so O(4^(MN)) space?

The complexity looks too large to be viable. Is there a better algorithm and is the complexity written correct?